# android:firebase-perf:NullPointException

Tags: android, firebase-performance

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.google.android.gms.internal.zzewh.zzb(com.google.android.gms.internal.zzewx)' on a null object reference
>          at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzevz.zza(Unknown Source:154)
>          at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzevz.zzb(Unknown Source:78)
>          at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzevz.zza(Unknown Source)
>          at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzewc.run(Unknown Source:6)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
>          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

Comment: Can you please add your code snippet?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you want people to help you then you need to describe your problem better. Check the logcat and all relevant parts of your code related to the issue. Post your code that is not working.